# Angles in a static equilibrium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, free-body-diagram, equilibrium, statics

I have three masses $\left(F_\alpha, \, F_\beta , \, \text{and}  \,F_g \right)$ with 2 pulleys, and a wind variable which is in static equilibrium. I have already calculated the appropriate forces for the 3 masses by multiplying it with $9.81 \, \frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}^{2}}$ (gravity).

$$
\begin{alignat}{7}
& F_{\text{wind}} && ~=~ & 60 \phantom{.0} & \, \mathrm{N}  \\[2px]
& F_{\alpha} && = & 313.9 & \, \mathrm{N} \\[2px]
& F_{\beta} && = & 619 \phantom{.0} & \, \mathrm{N} \\[2px]
& F_{g} && = & 882.9 & \, \mathrm{N} \\
\end{alignat}
$$

I'm required to find the angles for vector $F_\alpha$ and $F_\beta$ as shown in below equations (which is derived from the vector's individual components ($x$ and $y$):

$$
\begin{alignat}{7}
F_α \, \cos{\left( α \right)} & \, + \, F_β \, \cos {\left( β \right)} && + F_\text{wind} & ~=~ 0  \tag{1} \\[2px]
F_α \, \sin{\left(α\right)} & \, + \, F_β \, \sin {\left( β \right)} && - F_g & ~=~ 0  \tag{2}
\end{alignat}
$$

**Replacing these with actual values**: 
- 313.9cos α + 619cos β + 60 = 0  — (1)
 313.9sin α + 619sin β - 882.9 = 0  — (2)

How do I find the angle α & β from these two equations?

Edit 2:
[image]

I have re-organized the equation and square it as such:
cos²a = (619² cos²β + 60² + 2(619cosβ * 60)) / 313.9²
sin²a = (619² sin²β + 882.9² - 2(619sinβ * 882.9)) / 313.9²

Comment: Providing a diagram would be really useful here.

Comment: @Gert I will edit the post to include a free body diagram and what I've worked so far from below's guide

Comment: @Gert I have edited accordingly, though I'm not too sure whether my workings is correct or not.

Comment: The squaring of the right hand sides is not correct. You forgot the cross products of the terms.  $(x+y)^2 = x^2+y^2+2xy$.  I ** strongly ** suggest that you work hard to improve  your algebra or you will get totally lost in physics.

Comment: Truth be told my algebra is a little bit rusty. If taken on this context, squaring the right hand side will actually be (-619cosβ - 60)² / (-313.9)² which is then be -619²cos²β - 60² - 2(-619cosβ60)? @BillN

Comment: No.  What is $(-Y)^2$?

Comment: It will change into positive. I have edited the question, and has derived to this form: 0 = A + Bcosβ - Csinβ. From here onwards could someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: If you have that form, taking the first derivative of it will get rid of the $A$ term and leave you with some form $Bβ sinβ + Cβ cos β = 0$.  From there, finding β would be easy (hint:  tanβ)

Comment: Hint: Add the last two equations you post... there should be an identity that removes one of the variables and then you are left only with an equation to find the other one...

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the angle $\alpha$ from the equations with the trick the other answers give you <sup>*</sup>. But then you will end up with an equation of the form

$$ A \cos \beta + B \sin \beta + C = 0$$

To solve this do the following transformation

$$ \left. \begin{align}
  A & = R \cos \psi \\
  B & = R \sin \psi 
\end{align} \right\} 
\begin{aligned} 
  R & = \sqrt{A^2+B^2} \\
  \psi & = \arctan\left( \frac{B}{A} \right) 
\end{aligned}  $$

The equation is now $$ 
cos\beta\cos\psi + \sin\beta \sin\psi = \cos(\beta-\psi) = -\frac{C}{R} $$

which is solved for

$$ \begin{split} \beta & = \arccos\left( -\frac{C}{R} \right) + \psi \\
 & = \arccos\left( -\frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \right) + \arctan\left( \frac{B}{A} \right)\end{split}$$

<sub>footnotes:</sub>

- make the equations of this form 
  $$\begin{align} 
    \cos \alpha & = a \cos\beta+c_x \\
    \sin \alpha & = -a \sin \beta + c_y 
  \end{align}$$
- square both sides and add them for
  $$ 1 =  2 a c_x \cos\beta - 2 a c_y \sin\beta + c_x^2 + c_y^2 +a^2 $$
  $$ \left(2 a c_x\right) \cos\beta + \left(- 2 a c_y\right) \sin\beta + \left(c_x^2 + c_y^2 +a^2-1\right) = 0 $$
- Match the $A$, $B$ and $C$ coefficients.
- Once $\beta$ is known, then divide the two equations above for $$ \tan \alpha = \frac{c_y - a \sin\beta}{c_x + a \cos\beta} $$

**Edit 1**

Here is the actual solution:

$$\left. \begin{align}
  -313.9 \cos(\alpha) + 619 \cos(\beta) + 60 & = 0 \\
   313.9 \sin(\alpha)  + 619 \sin(\beta) - 882.9 & = 0 
\end{align} \right\} \begin{aligned}
   313.9 \cos(\alpha) & = 619 \cos(\beta) + 60 \\
   313.9 \sin(\alpha)  & = - 619 \sin(\beta) + 882.9
\end{aligned} $$

Square and add the two equations (on each side) to get

$$ \left. 98533.21 = 74280 \cos(\beta) - 1093030.2 \sin(\beta) + 1166273.41 \right\}\\ 74280 \cos(\beta) - 1093030.2 \sin(\beta) + 1067740.2 = 0 $$

$$ \begin{aligned} \beta & = \arccos\left( -\frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}} \right) + \arctan\left( \frac{B}{A} \right) \\
A & = 74280\\
B & = -1093030.2 \\
C & = 1067740.2\\
\beta &= 1.41284652 = 80.9501426° \\ \end{aligned} $$

Finally, $\alpha$ can be solved with the 2nd equation:

$$ \sin(\alpha) = 2.81267919-1.97196559 \sin(\beta) $$
$$ \alpha = 1.04567064 = 59.9125144° $$

Now you can plug the values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ into the two original equations to confirm it balances the forces.

Comment: Hi! May I know how did you derived the first 2 equation: cosα = acosβ+cx & sinα = −asinβ+cy  from?

Comment: In the OPs case, $A$ and $B$ are the same making the solution much easier than the general case you have outlined.

Comment: Hi I have to retract back as using this I didn't get the correct answer, α = 55.58°, β = 79.07°

Comment: The methods above are correct. The mistake must be somewhere else.

Comment: Your $\alpha=55.58°$ and $\beta=79.07°$ do not solve the system of equations. What does solve the system of equations is $$ \begin{align} \alpha & = 59.912514710332826° \\ \beta & = 80.950143077864119° \end{align} $$ which I get with my equations above.

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical solution trick when you have a system involving sine and cosine of the same unknown angle:
Re-organize the equations so that you have $$\cos\alpha = stuff $$ and $$\sin\alpha = other stuff.$$
Square these equations and add them. The angle $\alpha$ is eliminated because $$\sin^2\alpha + \cos^2\alpha = 1.$$

In your case, it's nice that the coefficiencts on both $\alpha$ terms are the same, and also on both $\beta$ terms.  You can use a double angle formula for the remaining $\beta$ terms to solve for $\beta.$ Then you can solve for $\alpha$.  Remember that tool, and teach it to someone else.

Comment: Hi, I will try to solve using this method, I have a quick question though. By squaring these equations (after I re-organizing) do I square the left hand side of the equation as well? (cosα & sinα)

Comment: Of course...do the algebra correctly. I assume you know algebra!

Comment: just basic ones though, not involving cos /sin functions, however would you like to take a look at my edit and see whether am I heading in the right direction? thanks! :)

Comment: Also if you divide both sides you will have $\tan \alpha = \frac{\ldots}{\ldots}$ which is solved for $\alpha$.

Comment: @ja72 No, because the right-hand sides contain sums of trig functions of the other angle, $\beta$.

Comment: Another solution method that saves a LOT of algebra work: set up equations (1) and (2) in an equation solver, and let the equation solver simultaneously manipulate both angles to drive both equations to zero.